# Buttons below the ListView

Tags: android, listview, button, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have the listView with set of items. And I want to add 2 buttons below the list. But if I do like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout

              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/fileManager"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center" >
     <LinearLayout

              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView

        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/fileManagerList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
    <CheckedTextView  
             android:id="@+id/checkedTextItem" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:gravity="center_vertical" 
             android:clickable="true"
             android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:paddingLeft="10dip" 
             android:paddingRight="6dip" 
             android:typeface="sans" android:textSize="16dip"/> 

     </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout

              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/fileManager"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:gravity="center" 
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fileManagerList">

             <Button
                android:id="@+id/attachFiles"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:background="#007FFF"
                android:gravity="center|center"

                android:text="Attach files"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fileManagerList"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelFiles"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:background="#838B83"
                android:gravity="center|center"  
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/attachFiles"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fileManagerList"
                android:text="Do not attach"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

my buttons displaying in each row of `ListView`. I tried do it the same way but using `RelativeLayout`, but I get correct list, buttons were in the bottom, but they overlay the last item of the list. How can I implement this?

Comment: please post your whole xml your xml is not properly posted.

Comment: [Follow this tutorial](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Layout, You can achieve your goal using the below XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relRingtone"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

            <ListView
             android:id="@+id/fileManagerList"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
             android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
             android:contentDescription="@string/ringtone"
             android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" 
             android:textSize="2dp" />

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/closecalmlayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fileManagerList" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btnOk"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                  android:layout_weight=".50"
                  />

              <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                  android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                  android:layout_weight=".50"
                   />

            </LinearLayout>  
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Buttons are showing in bottom and items from the listView not overlays them, but buttons show in each row of the listView...

Comment: Do you want button in bottom of the listview instead of parent bottom?

Comment: year, exactly! not in parent, but in the bottom of the ListView

Comment: I get                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout                                                                when triying to make android:layout_below="@+id/fileManagerList" .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15883/discussion-between-vino-and-user1512250)

Comment: Have you removed this line `android:layout_above="@+id/closecalmlayout"`  in listview

Comment: HURRRAY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!THANK YOU MAN!!!!My problem solved when I put my CheckedTextView to another xml file and your first answer, not edited, worked fine!!!Thank you!

Comment: No Worries.. I am glad that i helped to solve your problem.. Happy coding

Comment: I have had the same problem with circular references, and solved it by moving the referred items higher up in the xml file? for some reason it could then find the ID. I am sure it is a bug in android!

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are using ***@+id*** everywhere, wherever you are referring any id. Ex.:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fileManagerList"
```

Use "`@id/`" instead.

And also, try:

`android:layout_below="@id/fileManagerList"` // Add this attribute in button.

Comment: if I do like this, I get Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/closecalmlayout').

Comment: When you want to create a new id, then only you have to specify "@+id/" otherwise when you want to refer any id you need to ust use "@id/". I hope you have created "closecalmlayout" id before referring to layout_above attribute. If stil has problem then clean build your code. If still creates problem, delete R.java file and again clean build your code, or restart eclipse.